# What is the language of Live Templates in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, velocity, live-templates

What is the language of Live Templates in IntelliJ?

It this `Velocity` as in other templates?

Does this language have conditional operators?

I have the following code for default setter template in IntelliJ:

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
  static ##
#end
void set$StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project)))($field.type $paramName) {
  #if ($field.name == $paramName)
    #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
      this.##
    #else
      $classname.##
    #end
  #end
  $field.name = $paramName;
}
```

can I have the same in Live Template language?

Answer (score 0):

The language of live templates is not Velocity, it's much simpler: just variables (and expressions for their values). There's no control structures (conditions/loops) in live templates.

So you can't have "the same" in live templates, and it doesn't seem to make sense, because live templates and Generate templates are designed for different contexts and have access to different information. For example, when you generate a setter, you've chosen a corresponding field before and so have `$field` variable defined. But there's no such implicit context in live templates.